# Default value used inside a C++ class

Tags: c++

I have been reading a code and I am confused about a line in the code: 
Here is part of the code:

```
class mom_set
{
public:
    int nm;
    int *mom_ind,*mode_off,*mode_count,**mode;
    int n_mom,n_eff;
    int order;
.......
.....
    mom_set(int nm0=9):nm(nm0)
    { mom_ind=new int[(nm*2+1)*(nm*2+1)*(nm*2+1)];
      mode_off=new int[3*nm*nm+1];
      mode=new int*[3*nm*nm+1];
      mode_count=new int[3*nm*nm+1];
      clear();}
......
.....
};
```

I am not sure how to interpret this line "mom_set(int nm0=9):nm(nm0)" . Could you please explain?

Comment: Is this: ["What is this weird colon-member (“ : ”) syntax in the constructor?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) what you're asking about ?

Comment: Yes, that was another question I had about the " : " syntax. I haven't found something written this  way in the C++ book I am learning from.

Comment: Dunno which book that is, but that doesn't sound right. Member initialization is an important part of C++, and in-fact mandatory for `const` or reference members. Perhaps look deeper in your book or [try one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mom_set**: Same name as class name means it is constructor

**(int nm0=9)**: argument list. One argument of type `int` which is optional. If not passed, this argument is defaulted to value `9`

**:**: Start of [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

**nm(nm0)**: Member `nm` is initialized with value `nm0`

**{...}**: Rest of the constructor body